# SQL Insert assistance

Tags: sql

I have this query:

```
insert into OrderCounts (OpenOrders,ReadyOrders)
select t1.OpenOrders, t2.ReadyOrders
from
(select count(distinct(info.orderid)) as OpenOrders from LabworksDBProDPI.DBO.orderinfo info where info.orderstatusID = '1') t1,
(select count(distinct(info.orderid)) as ReadyOrders from LabworksDBProDPI.DBO.orderinfo info where info.orderstatusID = '2') t2
```

I have three columns:  Openorders, ready orders, Period

When I run this query I want to enter into the Period column the text of "PM".  I am not sure how to combine my query with the static text of "PM"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include it in the `select`:

```
insert into OrderCounts (OpenOrders, ReadyOrders, Period)
    select t1.OpenOrders, t2.ReadyOrders, 'PM'
    from (select count(distinct info.orderid) as OpenOrders
          from LabworksDBProDPI.DBO.orderinfo info
          where info.orderstatusID = '1'
         ) t1 cross join
         (select count(distinct info.orderid) as ReadyOrders
          from LabworksDBProDPI.DBO.orderinfo info
          where info.orderstatusID = '2'
         ) t2;
```

You could, of course, write this without the subqueries:

```
insert into OrderCounts (OpenOrders, ReadyOrders, Period)
    select count(distinct case when i.orderStatusId = 1 then i.orderid end),
           count(distinct case when i.orderStatusId = 2 then i.orderid end),
           'PM'
    from LabworksDBProDPI.DBO.orderinfo info i
    where i.orderstatusID in (1, 2);
```